# SQL Server : drop table with SQL parameters

Tags: sql, sqlparameter, drop-table

I'm trying to drop a table using `SqlParameters`. I have this code .

```
dbCon.Open();
DataRowView d= (DataRowView) cmbTabele.Items[cmbTabele.SelectedIndex];
string name = (d["table_name"]as string);

SqlCommand com=new SqlCommand("drop table @nume ", dbCon);
com.Parameters.Clear();
SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@nume", name);
com.Parameters.Add(param);

com.ExecuteNonQuery();   // ERROR HERE
dbCon.Close();
```

I receive this error :

> Incorrect syntax near '@nume'.

But when I do

```
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("drop table " + name, dbCon);
```

it works, and I really don't understand this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use a parameter for a table name.  Although you'll normally get told off around here for building up a query using string concatenation, this is one occasion where you'll need to!

```
SqlCommand com=new SqlCommand("drop table " + name, dbCon);
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not recommand it, but if you really want to use SQLParameter, then it is possible this way.

```
SqlCommand com=new SqlCommand("EXEC('drop table ''' + @nume + '''')", dbCon);
```

But really, there is no advantage in doing it this way. This work on SQL Server 2005 and newest version of it.